# How to ignore a bluetooth device for audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

**The Problem**

I am writing an app that uses a specific bluetooth 3.0 MFi device to receive data from a vehicle. Unfortunately the manufacturer of the device has set the bluetooth profile to headset. This means that when the phone is connected to the device but also connected to the in car bluetooth audio system and making a phone call / listening to music then the iPhone will intermittently switch from the in car bluetooth system to the bluetooth device used to retrieve data from the vehicle.

**The question**

How can i make iOS ignore a bluetooth device for audio?